# How do I stop Paw from converting my text input into dynamic values?

Tags: paw-app

I paste something with `:blah` and `:blah` is converted to a dynamic value `blah`. How do I stop this?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, this has been fixed in Paw 3.1.2 https://paw.cloud/updates/3.1.2